# How to sort a list of bigrams according to the second unigram?

Tags: python

I have a list of bigrams like this:

```
mylist = ["hello world", "this python", "black cat", "brown dog"]
```

I want to sort this list according to the second word in each element alphabetically. The result is like this:

```
mylist = ["black cat", "brown dog", "this python", "hello world"]
```

Could anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda s: s.split()[1])
```

result

```
['black cat', 'brown dog', 'this python', 'hello world']
```